# socket.io with Node.js 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to start new project - online chat, i think use socket.io, but recently released Node.js 4, and now it include net.socket class (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/). Is this socket.io, alternative or something else? I somehow heard that they want to merge. Should I start new projects with socket.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node always (or at least for a very long time now) included a net.socket class. It represents a TCP socket, which is something completely different from a websocket (though websockets do use TCP sockets, as does every communication over HTTP). And socket.io is a websocket (with fallbacks) library.

I don't think socket.io ever planned to merge with node. You're confusing it with io.js, which was a fork of node, and is now merged with it. That's why node jumped from version 0.12.x to 4.0, because io.js has versions 1.x - 3.x.

And yes, there is nothing stopping you from starting a new socket.io project.